# How to read values from registry in Pocket PC 2003 using c++?

Tags: c++, registry, volume, pocketpc, mute

I have to get the **current Mute state** from the following **registry values** as mentioned below:-

**For PPC 2002/2003:**

```
\HKCU\ControlPanel\Notifications\ShellOverrides\Mode
```

- 2 for Mute mode.
- 0 for Not-mute mode.

Not sure if other bits are used here for other things.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
LONG lReturn;
HKEY hkey;
DWORD dwLen, dwMode;

   lReturn = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"ControlPanel\\Notifications\\ShellOverrides",0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_READ,&hkey);
   if (lReturn == ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
      dwLen = sizeof(DWORD);
      lReturn = RegQueryValueEx(hkey,"Mode", NULL, NULL,(LPBYTE)&dwMode, &dwLen);
      RegCloseKey(hkey);
   }
```